# cannot read property 'setTitleText' of undefined - ccui.Button

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-js, cocos2d-html5

I am unable to setTitle Text for ccui.Buttona a widget, its showing cannot read property 'setTitleText' of undefined in Cocos2d-JS

Here's the code

```
    SolutionGrid.setEmptySolutionBox = function(selChild,rChar) {

    selChild.active = true;
    cc.log("get tag of empty solutionBpx" + selChild.getTag());
    var textButtons = ((ccui.Button)(selChild.getChildByTag(5)));
    //var textButtons = ccui.Button(selChild.getChildren()[0]);
    if(textButtons===null){
        cc.log("get tag of empty solutionBpx NULL");
    }
    ///cc.log("get tag of empty solutionBpx" + textButtons.getTag());
    textButtons.setTitleText("a");

};
```

where selChild is node on which ccui.Button is added

Here how its added , I am getting the tag of that node but can not find the ccui.Button as its child

```
solBox.addChild(textButton,5,5); //solBox is CCNode and text button is ccui.Button
```

Comment: what is ccui? Where is it declared, initialized?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: ccui.Button is the http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.0alpha/symbols/ccui.Button.html .. It is intiliazed i.e. textButton i just gave a snippet and added as a child of Node (solBox) with tag 5

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var textButtons = ((ccui.Button)(selChild.getChildByTag(5)));
```

with

```
var textButtons = selChild.getChildByTag(5);
```